# USB Settings in android not getting stored

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, android-framework

I am new to android framework. I am working with USB Settings. I want to know where are USB settings stored in android. 
I am having following problem :
when i connect my phone to Computer and select one of the option from mass storage, MTP,PTP and now if I switch off and then switch on the device my selection get cleared. I want the previous selection to be retained.
What should I do..??

Thanks in advance...

Edit : I discovered today that usb_device_manager.xml file should be created in /data/system folder but in my case it is not getting generated.
I am unable to find what is the reason behind this.
The file that creates this file is located at frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/usb/

Waiting for positive reply...

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html

Comment: it doesn't containing setting regarding usb state i.e. mtp or ptp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbManager.html
You cannot find an open API for getting this information.
However, from the source code we can see this two functions:

```
/**
 * Name of the MTP USB function.
 * Used in extras for the {@link #ACTION_USB_STATE} broadcast
 *
 * {@hide}
 */
public static final String USB_FUNCTION_MTP = "mtp";

/**
 * Name of the PTP USB function.
 * Used in extras for the {@link #ACTION_USB_STATE} broadcast
 *
 * {@hide}
 */
public static final String USB_FUNCTION_PTP = "ptp";


 /**
     * Returns the current default USB function.
     *
     * @return name of the default function.
     *
     * {@hide}
     */
    public String getDefaultFunction() {
        String functions = SystemProperties.get("persist.sys.usb.config", "");
        int commaIndex = functions.indexOf(',');
        if (commaIndex > 0) {
            return functions.substring(0, commaIndex);
        } else {
            return functions;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets the current USB function.
     * If function is null, then the current function is set to the default function.
     *
     * @param function name of the USB function, or null to restore the default function
     * @param makeDefault true if the function should be set as the new default function
     *
     * {@hide}
     */
    public void setCurrentFunction(String function, boolean makeDefault) {
        try {
            mService.setCurrentFunction(function, makeDefault);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "RemoteException in setCurrentFunction", e);
        }
    }
```

It is not recommended to use hidden APIs, but this might solve your problem.
If you wants to know how to use the hidden APIs, refer to this link:
http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-1-introduction/

Comment: Hi Robin. I ve reached till here but where is the definition of mService.setCurrentFunction. How is the value stored in android..??

Comment: Sorry to make you confused. This source code is UsbManager.java from Android AOSP. The mService is the usb service. You shall not use this service. You can use either UsbManager.getDefaultFunction() or SystemProperties.get("persist.sys.usb.config", ""), these two are all hidden APIs.

Comment: Hi Robin. /data/system/usb_device_manager.xml file is not getting generated in my case...